# iMessage badge count not showing up on my iPhone

Tags: ios, messages, notifications

On my iPhone 6s the iMessage count (on the Messages app icon) is no longer showing up? I checked Settings > Notifications > Messages and it is showing active.

Can someone tell me what I need to do going forward?

Comment: I'm confused by what you are asking.  Notifications show a lot more things than messages.  What do you mean by notifications is showing active?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). In the meantime, can I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/368713/edit) your question to include a screenshot of your settings at Settings > Notifications > Messages? It's just that saying *"it is showing active"* is a little ambiguous as there are a number of settings there.